# Запуск android приложений на двух устройствах

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

У меня в проекте два приложения. Клиент и сервер. Комп не тянет эмулятор. Можно ли подключить два смартфона по USB и на каждом запустить свое приложение?

Comment: Вы хотите запускать сервер на Андроиде? Сомнительная затея - насколько знаю мобильное устройство не принимает входящих подключений. Все соединения типа "телефон<->телефон" делаются через промежуточный сервер, то есть на самом деле это "телефон->сервер<-телефон". В остальном да, можно подключить несколько аппаратов и устанавливать/запускать на любом из них или даже на всех разом

Comment: SocketServer.listen в Java. Стандартные классы на Android все по идее должны работать?

Comment: По идее должны, но при чём тут классы... Речь идёт о сетевой безопасности. Если клиент и сервер на одном устройстве - они соединятся без проблем через `localhost`, если на разных, то шиш. Если сервер на ПК, то ему можно разрешить принимать подключения - в телефоне же таких настроек просто нет, по крайней мере без рут-доступа. Хотя в локальной домашней сети наверное будет работать. Если вы делаете сервер для домашней сети, P2P и тп, то попробуйте. Если просто для теста, а в последствии сервер будет размещён в интернете, то лучше запускать его прямо на десктопной java без Андроидов с эмуляторами

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли подключить два смартфона по USB и на каждом запустить свое приложение?

Да, можно. Подключите их к разным USB портам и получите 2 телефона. Только надо в каждый телефон грузить отдельно разные приложения. Если запустить стандартный `install task gradle` - то он установит приложение во все подключенные аппараты.

Лучше управлять установкой врукопашную из `shell`, например:

```
adb devices  //выдаст список подсоединенных аппаратов
```

далее можно уже устанавливать на каждый аппарат отдельные приложения, типа:

```
adb -s <имя устройства> install example.apk
```